# Expected single matching bean but found 3: objectMapper,halObjectMapper,_halObjectMapper in junitTest

Tags: java, spring, junit, kotlin, spring-junit

I'm having a problem with my testing. I'm using java spring and trying to run junit test to check if my server is alive.

This the **test** I'm trying:

```
  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
  @ContextConfiguration(classes = arrayOf(ServiceContext::class,DatabaseContext::class))
@Transactional
open class newtest : AbstractTestController(){

 @Test
fun echoTest() {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/echo").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk)
  }
}
```

This is the **AbstractTestController class that my newtest class is extending**:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
abstract class AbstractTestController : DatabaseInitializedTest() {

 @Autowired
lateinit var webAppContext: WebApplicationContext

 lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc


@Autowired
lateinit var authHelper: OAuthHelper



@Autowired
private lateinit var userService: UserService

fun adminToken(username: String) = authHelper.addBearerToken(userService.getUserByUsername(username), *AuthoritiesService.adminAuthorities.toTypedArray())

fun clientItToken(username: String) = authHelper.addBearerToken(userService.getUserByUsername(username), *AuthoritiesService.clientItAuthorities.toTypedArray())
fun clientManagerToken(username: String) = authHelper.addBearerToken(userService.getUserByUsername(username), *AuthoritiesService.clientManagerAuthorities.toTypedArray())

 fun endUserToken(username: String) = authHelper.addBearerToken(userService.getUserByUsername(username), *AuthoritiesService.endUserAuthorities.toTypedArray())

@Autowired
lateinit var mapper: ObjectMapper


 fun <T> ResultActions.and200ReturnClass(clazz: TypeReference<T>): ResultActions {
if (this.andReturn().response.status == HttpServletResponse.SC_OK
    && this.andReturn().response.contentAsString.isNotEmpty()) {
  mapper.readValue<T>(this.andReturn().response.contentAsString, clazz)!!
  }
return this
}

 @Before
fun initialize() {
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
    .webAppContextSetup(webAppContext)
    .apply<DefaultMockMvcBuilder>(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
    .alwaysDo<DefaultMockMvcBuilder>(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
    .build()
   }
}
```

**My configuration**:

```
   @Configuration
  @Import(value = *arrayOf(
    OAuth2ServerConfiguration::class,
    OAuth2ServerConfiguration.AuthorizationServerConfiguration::class,
    OAuth2ServerConfiguration.ResourceServerConfiguration::class,
    SecurityConfig::class,
    OAuthHelper::class,
    WebConfig::class,
    DatabaseInitializator::class,
    LowerCaser::class))


 @ComponentScan("com.hyg","com.hyg.service", "com.hyg.web", "com.hyg.utils")
 @EnableAutoConfiguration
 @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
 open class ServiceContext

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.hyg")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
open class DatabaseContext {

 val DATA_PACKAGE = "com.hyg.data"
 val INTERCEPTOR_KEY = "hibernate.ejb.interceptor"


 @Value("\${spring.datasource.username:${Const.NONE}}")
 lateinit var username: String

 @Value("\${spring.datasource.url}")
 lateinit var url: String

 @Value("\${spring.datasource.driverClassName}")
 lateinit var driverClass: String

  @Value("\${spring.datasource.password}")
  lateinit var password: String


 @Bean
 @Primary
 open fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
 val mapper = ObjectMapper()
 mapper.registerModule(KotlinModule())
 mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true)
 mapper.configure(MapperFeature.USE_STD_BEAN_NAMING, true)
 mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT, false)
 mapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())

 mapper.registerModule(localDateTimeSerializer())
 return mapper
   }

@Bean
open fun localDateTimeSerializer(): SimpleModule {
val localDateTimeSerializer = SimpleModule()
val serializer = LocalDateTimeSerializer(
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(Const.DATE_TIME_PATTERN))

val deserializer = LocalDateTimeDeserializer(
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(Const.DATE_TIME_PATTERN))

localDateTimeSerializer.addSerializer(LocalDateTime::class.java, serializer)
localDateTimeSerializer.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime::class.java, deserializer)

return localDateTimeSerializer
 }


 @Bean
 open fun dataSource(): DataSource {

  val ds =  DataSourceBuilder.create().driverClassName(driverClass).username(username).password(password).url(url).build()
val proxy = ProxyDataSource()
proxy.setDataSource(ds)
proxy.setListener(DataSourceQueryCountListener())
return proxy
 }

 @Bean
  open fun entityManagerFactory(
      factory: EntityManagerFactoryBuilder, dataSource: DataSource,
      properties: JpaProperties): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
val jpaProperties = HashMap<String, Any>()
jpaProperties.putAll(properties.getHibernateProperties(dataSource))
jpaProperties.put(INTERCEPTOR_KEY, hibernateInterceptor())
return factory.dataSource(dataSource).packages(DATA_PACKAGE)
        .properties(jpaProperties as MutableMap<String, *>)
        .build()
   }

 @Bean
open fun hibernateInterceptor(): HibernateStatisticsInterceptor {
  return HibernateStatisticsInterceptor()
}

@Bean
open fun requestStatisticsInterceptor(): RequestStatisticsInterceptor {
  return RequestStatisticsInterceptor()
   }
 }
```

This is the full **Error** I'm getting:

```
   2017-11-17 20:03:52.477  WARN   --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointMBeanExportAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointMBeanExportAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ecfe2bfa]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: objectMapper,halObjectMapper,_halObjectMapper
 2017-11-17 20:03:52.477  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-11-17 20:03:52.499  INFO   --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-11-17 20:03:52.508 ERROR   --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@6b19b79] to prepare test instance [com.hyginex.Integration.newtest@7a08da83]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointMBeanExportAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointMBeanExportAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ecfe2bfa]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: objectMapper,halObjectMapper,_halObjectMapper
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:279)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1056)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:134)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
... 24 common frames omitted
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointMBeanExportAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ecfe2bfa]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: objectMapper,halObjectMapper,_halObjectMapper
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271)
... 41 common frames omitted
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: objectMapper,halObjectMapper,_halObjectMapper
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:172)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1114)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getIfAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1643)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointMBeanExportAutoConfiguration.<init>(EndpointMBeanExportAutoConfiguration.java:63)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointMBeanExportAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ecfe2bfa.<init>(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
... 43 common frames omitted
```

Hope it will help to solve my problem.
I tried so far to put @Primary on the Bean that make the ObjectMapper or to add those annotation @Order
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean but it didn't work...
Thank you

Comment: someone has an answer?

Answer (score 4):

You have several beans with the type `ObjectMapper` in the Spring Context. Try to add the annotation `@Qualifier("objectMapper")` for `mapper` (in `AbstractTestController`) or rename it to `objectMapper`:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
abstract class AbstractTestController : DatabaseInitializedTest() {
...
@Qualifier("objectMapper")
@Autowired
lateinit var mapper: ObjectMapper
...
}
```

or

```
@WebAppConfiguration
abstract class AbstractTestController : DatabaseInitializedTest() {
...
@Autowired
lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper
...
}
```